# conj not adding to end of vector when called via recur

Tags: clojure

Why does this keep asking Jack if he wants a cup of tea and not the other fathers.

```
(defn tea-anyone
  "Ask 'fathers' if they would like some tea"
  [fathers]
  (loop [asks 0 to-ask fathers]
    (let [[father & others] to-ask]
      (println (str "Cup of tea " father "? "))
        (if (> asks 6)
          (println (str father ": All right then!"))
          (recur (inc asks) (conj others father))))))

(tea-anyone ["Jack" "Ted" "Dougle"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `others` isn't a vector. See for yourself:

```
(let [[f & o :as a] [1 2 3 4]]
    (println f)
    (println o)
    (println a)
    (println (type f))
    (println (type o))
    (println (type a))
    (println (type (conj o 5)))
    (println (type (conj a 5))))
```

To achieve the effect you want, you could use [`cycle`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cycle).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
`(recur (inc asks) (conj (vec others) father))`